# How to use xcolor package's `named` keyword

Tags: color

1. When and why would I use the `named` keyword of the `xcolor` package?

   In particular, consider the following scenario. Suppose I define a new color, `MyNewCol`, using a color, `MyOldCol`, which I've defined previously. What do I specify as the model? `named`?

   \definecolor{MyNewCol}{MODEL}{MyOldCol}
2. According to [David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375686/21685),

   > `named` is a colour model like `rgb` or `cmyk`

   However `rgb` and `cmyk` (as well as all the other color models except from `named`) have a fixed domain of values, for instance in the case of `rgb` the domain is [0,1]^3 and in the case of `cmyk` it is [0,1]^4. What is the fixed domain of values of the named model?

   Is the following statement correct?

   > The specification of the `named` model consists of all the base colors listed in section 4.1 of [the `xcolor` manual](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf),  and, if one or more of the package options `dvipsnames`, `svgnames`, `x11names` is specified, then additionally all the color names specified in the corresponding list(s) given in sections 4.2-4.4 of the manual, respectively.

Comment: I do not understand the question added in edit `\definecolor{MyNewCol}{MODEL}{MyOldCol}` `\definecolor` does not define colours in terms of a previously defined colour are you thinking of `\colorlet` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I didn't realize that `\definecolor` can't be used with previously defined colors. This is an important piece of the puzzle. Thanks! What about point #2? Is the statement that I highlighted in the end correct?

Comment: If you had made an actual example of defining a colour you would see that (irrespective of named colours) the syntax was not correct. As for the second part I assume it's correct, why shouldn't it be?

Answer (score 6):

This comes from the `color` package, `named` is a colour model like `rgb` or `cmyk` so the question isn't whether the user accesses the definition by name, but whether the colour is defined by name rather than numeric values at the back end. so for example using latex+dvips the back end driver knows a color `GreenYellow` and latex can use that colour via the named colour model without having any information about what colour that is. (It's `{cmyk}{0.15,0,0.69,0}` but you only need to know that if defining `GreenYellow` for some system that does not have this name built in.)

Comment: Is there any situation where *not* specifying the keyword `named` would lead to an error or unexpected/undefined behavior? Or is it merely used to optimize performance (i.e. speed of processing)?

Comment: @EvanAad your question didn't have an example so it is hard to guess what you are doing, but the colour model is never optional you always have to specify what model you are using when you define a colour.

Comment: What if I define a new color using a user-defined color that I've defined previously. What color model should I specify in the new color's definition? `named`?

Comment: I've added a sub-question to my original question with an example code.

Comment: @EvanAad there is really no point ever defining a colour using the named model. It is there to support the existing names built in to the dvips driver.

Comment: So what model should I specify in the example given in my post?

Comment: Another thing that I don't understand is this. You wrote in your answer that "`named` is a colour model like `rgb` or `cmyk`". However `rgb` and `cmyk` as well as all the other color models have a fixed domain of values, for instance in the case of `rgb` the domain is [0,1]^3 and in the case of `cmyk` it is [0,1]^4. What is the fixed domain of values of the `named` model?

Comment: @EvanAad it is the fixed set of names that are provided by the system you are using, if you use dvips it has 68 predefined named colours. The color package allows you to fake the named model with colour definitions to make it easier to move between latex+dvips and pdflatex (which predefines no names) but the only reason to _use_ the named colour model is to use the fixed names provided by the system.

Comment: @EvanAad the model you specify to `\definecolor` has to be the syntax that you use in the final argument to specify a  colour, you can not use `MyOldCol`, a real example always makes questions clearer, your fragments of code are very confusing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60706/discussion-between-evan-aad-and-david-carlisle).

Answer (score 3):

> 1) … `\definecolor` does not define colours in terms of a previously
>   defined colour are you thinking of `\colorlet`?
>
> 2) I didn't realize that `\definecolor` can't be used with previously
>   defined colors. This is an important piece of the puzzle.

Actually, `\definecolor` *does* allow you to reference using the `named` model — including not only the names of base colors (and any additional colors enabled by package options) but also any named color you have already defined with another `\definecolor` command. See MWE below and its output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{anothercolor}{named}{mycolor}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\textcolor{mycolor}{This is \texttt{mycolor}.}\\
\textcolor{anothercolor}{This is \texttt{anothercolor}.}
\end{document}
```

[image]